# Как вернуть блок на прежнее место спустя время?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть блок, который я отключаю с помощью ***SetActive***. Затем проверяю, активен ли объект с помощью ***ActiveSelf***. Но по моей задумке блок не появляется спустя некое время.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IceBlockDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

    bool onBlock;
    Animator anim;
    public float waitAfterStepped;
    public float waitAfterDestroy;
    public IceBlockDestroy block;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        block = gameObject.GetComponent<IceBlockDestroy>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(!block.gameObject.activeSelf){

            waitAfterDestroy-=Time.deltaTime;

            if(waitAfterDestroy < 0){

                block.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                anim.SetBool ("isStepped", false);

            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
    {

        if (onBlock) {

            anim.SetBool ("isStepped", true);
            waitAfterStepped-=Time.deltaTime;

            if(waitAfterStepped < 0){

                block.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
        onBlock = true;

    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(){

        onBlock = false;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** как вернуть блок? Уместен ли тут SetActive и ActiveSelf?

Comment: В теории выглядит более менее, если не считать факт, что ты переменным waitAfterStepped  и waitAfterDestroy не возвращаешь первоначальные значения после операций. Но, я бы порекомендовал взять VisualStudio или MonoDevelop, поставить breakpoint на том месте, где кажется должна происходить логика появления и посмотреть что происходит, какие данные получаются в переменных и что не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то ты сделал кое-что смешное: ты повесил скрипт на каждый блок. При этом в переменную `block` ты помещаешь ссылку на компонент **этого же** блока. Как следствие в строке:

```
block.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

ты делаешь неактивным тот самый блок, на котором исполняется скрипт. Логично, что когда он делается неактивным — он отключается. В результате чего метод `Update` и другие методы уже не работают (зачем движку вхолостую их гонять?).

Вот если бы у тебя в переменной `block` лежала ссылка на объект (положил бы через редактор), то ты бы работал с `block.gameObject` уже того *другого* объекта. А так: сам себе яму выкопал.

В общем решений как минимум два:

1. Делаешь какой-то общий менеджер по работе с блоками, в котором будет массив/список, в общем коллекция этих блоков. Этот менеджер, как раз управляет этими блоками, в том числе их появлением и исчезанием (например блок при прыжке на него рассылает сообщение "На меня прыгнули!", а менеджер получает сообщение и реагирует).
2. Вместо того, чтобы делать `SetActive`, можешь изменять два параметра:

   - Прозрачнось (альфа канал) у материала
   - Отключать/включать `BoxCollider2D` (или какой у тебя там коллайдер висит)

   В этом случае скрипт продолжит работать в штатном режиме, но объект будет и появляться и исчезать как и задумано.

---

Также напомню, что  переменным `waitAfterStepped` и `waitAfterDestroy` ты не возвращаешь первоначальные значения после операций. В итоге они после первого же исчезания/появления останутся в отрицательном значении.

Еще я бы порекомендовал иногда (всегда) разрабатывать в IDE  *VisualStudio* или *MonoDevelop*, в которых иногда (всегда) в непонятных ситуациях заниматься отладкой: поставить `breakpoint` на том месте, где кажется должна происходить задуманная логика и посмотреть что происходит, какие данные получаются в переменных и что не так.

Comment: Насчёт waitAfterStepped и waitAfterDestroy, да. Забылся. Работаю по умолчанию в Mono. Попробую ваши предложения.